# Joomla! 2.5.22, can't complete the localhost installation

Tags: mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin, joomla2.5

I got a problem while installing Joomla 2.5.22, the problem appers in the 4 step "Database", I've configured the database but when the creating tables process starts it just create some tables! and the procress turns into a loop

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 0):

before installing joomla, open installation/SQL/mysql/joomla.sql file with an editor like notepad++ and replace all `"ENGINE=InnoDB"` with `"ENGINE=MyIsam"`, save it and try to install joomla again.

this way worked for joomla 3.2, maybe the new updates of joomla 2.5 have the same problem!